# Sort arraylist of letters and numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort an arraylist of strings made up of numbers and letters, an example of the list once sorted would be:

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 11
name 12
name 13
```

But when I use collections.sort() it sorts this way:

```
name 1
name 11
name 12
name 13
name 2
name 3
```

Any ideas what the type of sort I'm looking for would be called or how do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String`s are ordered alphabetically by default. You need to implement your own `Comparator<String>` or use an object that implements `Comparable` (or use a `Comparator` with it) to solve this, especially since the `String`s you are using are mixtures of words and integers.

Answer (score 1):

Implement comprable, override compareTo, parse the intand the name out and then you can sort by both of them. Do you want to sort soley by number or by both

Answer (score 1):

This happens because it's sorting alphabetically, looking for one character at a time.

```
name 13
name 2
```

Here, "`name` " is the same part, moving forward, you have "`1`" and "`2`". `1` comes before `2`. Remember `13` and `2` are just Strings here not numbers.

You can [write your own comparator](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/). To achieve what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashMap<Integer,String> map` and can sort it

Answer (score 0):

as advised by others, you can write your own `Comparator` as shown below

```
      Comparator<? super String> myComparator = new Comparator<String>() {

        public int compare(String name1, String name2) {
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(name1.split(" ")[1]);
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(name2.split(" ")[1]);
            // > : Increasing order 
            // < : Decreasing order
            if(num1 < num2)
                    return 1;
            else
                    return -1;
        }

      };
      Collections.sort(names, myComparator);
```

Output:

> name 91
>   name 12
>   name 11
>   name 2